# Get Child categories magento

Tags: php, magento

Trying to get child of a specific category which is active. Please help. I am having trouble doing it. I'm currently able to show them all but not specifically. Would appreciate any help.

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(2);
$category->getChildCategories();
$tree = $category->getTreeModel();
$tree->load();
$ids = $tree->getCollection()->getAllIds();
```

Comment: Get all the child category details, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-sub-category-details-by-parent-id-magento/

Answer (score 36, accepted):

here is code to load active category

```
/* Load category by id*/
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);


/*Returns comma separated ids*/
$subcats = $cat->getChildren();

//Print out categories string
#print_r($subcats);

foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid)
{
  $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
  if($_category->getIsActive())
  {
    $caturl     = $_category->getURL();
    $catname     = $_category->getName();
    if($_category->getImageUrl())
    {
      $catimg     = $_category->getImageUrl();
    }
    echo '<h2><a href="'.$caturl.'" title="View the products for this category"><img src="'.$catimg.'" alt="" />'.$catname.'</a></h2>';
  }
}
?>
```

hope this is sure help you.

Comment: Use getAllChildren and pass true to it, this will return an array. No need to explode the string. Lyle Mcclanahan offers the best advice

Comment: In terms of performance this is really bad. 3-4 categories would be okay, imagine loading 300 instances of the category model...

Comment: you can use tree node structure then with cache tags

Comment: Just make a note: `$cat->getAllChildren(true)` will return a array which include own id and all its children ids.

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned by mhaupt, it is faster to load a collection rather than each category in a loop. But, as far as I am concerned, there is no need to manually load the child categories. Basically this is what `$category->getChildrenCategories()` already does.

There is also a filter to get active categories only. Just call `addIsActiveFilter()` on the collection.

**a.) Load active child categories via `getChildren()`**

```
// 1. Get a list of all child category ids (e.g "12,23,11,42")
$subcategoryIds = $category->getChildren();

// 2. Create collection
$categoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();

// 3. Add all attributes to select, otherwise you can not 
//    access things like $cat->getName() etc.
$categoryCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

// 4. Filter by ids
$categoryCollection->addIdFilter($subcategoryIds);

// 5. Add filter to collection to get active categories only
$categoryCollection->addIsActiveFilter();
```

**b.) Load active child categories with `getChildrenCategories()`**

```
// 1. Load collection
$categoryCollection= $category->getChildrenCategories();

// 2. Add filter to collection to get active categories only
$categoryCollection->addIsActiveFilter();
```

The collection will be loaded form the database as soon as it is accessed. If the collection is not loaded and `$subcategories->count()` is called only a "SELECT count(*)" will be fired against the database (in contrast to `count($subcategories)` which will force the collection to load itself).

**Iterating the collection**

```
foreach($categoryCollection as $category) {
    echo $category->getName();
}
```

If you add more filters to the collection after accessing it, the collection will not load itself again automatically. To apply changes to the collection, just call `$categoryCollection->load()` to reload the collection from the database.

Comment: `getChildrenCategories` will give you a *loaded* and *active-filtered* collection (see `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category::getChildrenCategories()`). Not only `addIsActiveFilter`is redundant, but useless, as any other subsequent collection-altering call, because the collection is already loaded. Maybe this method is better: `\Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::getCategories($parent, $recursionLevel = 0, $sorted=false, $asCollection=false, $toLoad=true)`.

Answer (score 5):

Those who are saying to use getAllChildren() instead of getChildren() are simply wrong. 
Both methods return the exact same thing, with one difference, getAllChildren(true) will return an array instead of a comma delimited string. getAllChildren($bool asArray) defaults to false. My point being that either way you're going to have to use

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
```

inside of a loop unless you use the function below.

```
private function fetchCatsById($onlyThese)
{
    $cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                ->getCollection(true)
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addIdFilter($onlyThese)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('level','2')
                ->addIsActiveFilter();

    return $cats;
}

$cats = $this->fetchCatsById($onlyThese);
```

Comment: This is the proper way to do it, shame it's last on here

Answer (score 2):

The one answer liyakat wrote, should not be used in professional shops, because it raises a performance issue, because of the multiple n time loads of the category object, rather use the collection of categories for that, get all children

```
$cat->getAllChildren()
```

, then limit the category collection by the needed category ids like

```
$coll->addIdFilter($idFilter);
```

then you won't have to load n times against the database.

Please do keep in mind that loads within loops are one of the most often used bad code examples in any Magento projects and to avoid them!

Answer (score 1):

Hello you will see below code

```
$category_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category'); 
  $_category = $category_model->load(13); 
  $all_child_categories = $category_model->getResource()->getAllChildren($_category);
  print_r($all_child_categories);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want any number of subcategories of parent category than Click here http://magentoo.blogspot.com/2014/01/get-all-subcategories-of-parent-category-magento.html