# Magento show all child categories on child category

Tags: magento, navigation

I have been searching high and low for this answer.  I would be extremely grateful if someone can point me in the right direction. I would like to show all other child categories on a child category in my sidebar navigation.

As an example...

INSTEON

- INSTEON Starter Kits
- INSTEON Responders
- INSTEON Controllers
- INSTEON Accessories

When selecting a child category of INSTEON (INSTEON Responders as an example) - I would still like the other children to display (please see http://www.smarthome.com.au/insteon.html). Ideally the current child should be bold and the other children normal.

I believe I need to edit app/design/frontend/theme/subtheme/template/catalog/navigation/left.phtml

```
<!--Added by Brad - Get current category -->
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry("current_category"); ?>
<?php if (!Mage::registry('current_category')) return ?>
<?php $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories() ?>
<?php $_count = is_array($_categories)?count($_categories):$_categories->count(); ?>
<?php if($_count): ?>
<div class="block block-layered-nav">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Browse By') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <dl id="narrow-by-list2">
<!--Added by Brad - Display current category name -->
            <dt><h2><?php echo $currentCategory->getName(); ?><?php echo $this->__('') ?></h2></dt>
            <dd>
                <ol>
                <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                    <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($_category)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?></a> (<?php echo $_category->getProductCount() ?>)
                    </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </ol>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list2')</script>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry("current_category"); ?>
<?php if (!Mage::registry('current_category')) return ?>
<?php $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories() ?>

<?php $parent = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategory()->getId(); ?>
<?php $parent = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parent); ?>
<?php $siblings = explode(',', $parent->getChildren()); ?>

<?php $_count = is_array($_categories)?count($_categories):$_categories->count(); ?>
<?php if($_count): ?>
<div class="block block-layered-nav block-layered-nav--no-filters">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Browse By') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content toggle-content open">
        <p class="block-subtitle block-subtitle--filter"><?php echo $this->__('Filter') ?></p>
        <dl id="narrow-by-list2">
            dt><?php echo $this->__('Category') ?></dt>
            <dd>
                <ol>
                <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                    <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($_category)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>>
                            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?>
                            <span class="count">(<?php echo $_category->getProductCount() ?>)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </ol>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list2')</script>
    </div>
</div>

<?php elseif(count($siblings > 1)): ?>
<div class="block block-layered-nav block-layered-nav--no-filters">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Browse By') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content toggle-content open">
        <p class="block-subtitle block-subtitle--filter"><?php echo $this->__('Filter') ?></p>
        <dl id="narrow-by-list2">
            dt><?php echo $this->__('Category') ?></dt>
            <dd>
                <ol>
                <?php foreach($siblings as $sibling_id): ?>
                    <?php $sibling = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sibling_id); ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($sibling) ?>"<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($sibling)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>>
                            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($sibling->getName()) ?>
                            <span class="count">(<?php echo $sibling->getProductCount() ?>)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </ol>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list2')</script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use

```
$parent_category_id = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategory()->getId();
```

to get the parent category id. Then

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parent_category_id);
```

to load the entire parent category.  With that you can load the parent category's children (see [Get Child categories magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525419/get-child-categories-magento)).

--EDIT--

```
<!--Added by Brad - Get current category -->
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry("current_category"); ?>
<?php if (!Mage::registry('current_category')) return ?>
<?php $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories() ?>

<!-- My code -->
<?php $parent = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategory()->getId(); ?>
<?php $parent = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parent); ?>
<?php $siblings = explode(',', $parent->getChildren()); ?>

<?php $_count = is_array($_categories)?count($_categories):$_categories->count(); ?>
<?php if($_count): ?>
<div class="block block-layered-nav">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Browse By') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <dl id="narrow-by-list2">
<!--Added by Brad - Display current category name -->
            <dt><h2><?php echo $currentCategory->getName(); ?><?php echo $this->__('') ?></h2></dt>
            <dd>
                <ol>
                <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                    <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($_category)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?></a> (<?php echo $_category->getProductCount() ?>)
                    </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </ol>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list2')</script>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- this will only show if there are no child categories of current child (and there are siblings) -->
<?php elseif(count($siblings > 1)): ?>
<!-- show sibling categories if have any -->
    <?php foreach($siblings as $sibling_id): ?>
        <?php if($sibling_id == $currentCategory->getId()): ?>
<!-- CURRENT CATEGORY -->
        <?php else: ?>
<!-- SIBLING CATEGORY -->
            <?php $sibling = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sibling_id); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.  Although this is not the question I am asking (my mistake - should have been clearer). I already have children showing (see code above). The issues is I would like all "sisters" of the current child to show when in a child category. At the moment, once you enter the lowest child, the category list in the sidebar disappears. Thanks.

Comment: Edited my answer to show what I was talking about, hopefully that clarified things.  The bottom does need to be formatted, but there should be enough information there now.  Also, since I don't know your project, I didn't know when you want to show sibling categories, so I only have them showing if the current category has no children.  Showing them all the time would mean putting the if($_count) block in the CURRENT CATEGORY block and touching up the code a bit.