# How To properly call url from category in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to make custom category listing in Magento 1.9.1 
My problem is , when I'm trying to get Url of category and I'm trying to enter category I got error

```
WHOOPS, OUR BAD...
The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why...()
```

This is code:

```
    <?php
$parent = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(13);
$childrenCollection = $parent->getCollection();
$childrenCollection->addIdFilter($parent->getChildren());
$childrenCollection->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1);
$childrenCollection->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('all_children')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('is_anchor')
    ->setOrder('position', Varien_Db_Select::SQL_ASC)
    ->joinUrlRewrite();
$childrenCollection->addAttributeToSelect('image');
?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach($childrenCollection as $cat): ?>
        <li>
<!--            FIRST METHOD--> 


            <a href="<?php echo $cat->getUrlKey(); ?>.html" title="<?php echo $cat->getName(); ?>">
           //RETURNS http://localhost/projectname/index.php/product-name.html
                <img class="cat-image" src="<?php echo $cat->getImageUrl(); ?>" />
            </a>
<!--            SECOND METHOD-->
            <a href="<?php echo $cat->getURL(); ?>.html" title="<?php echo $cat->getName(); ?>">
            //RETURNS http://localhost/projectname/index.php/catalog/category/view/s/product-name/id/14/
                <img class="cat-image" src="<?php echo $cat->getImageUrl(); ?>" />
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Thanks for all advices , best regards

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding your question, there are [many questions on this topic with good answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18525419/1737136).